# wp editor settings array autosave function onchange

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, tinymce, wp-editor

I'm trying to set up an autosave for dynamic wp editors in case my users forget to click save. (Currently set up with AJAX button to save.) Users can have 0 to 20 separate entries.

It seems that something should be added to the wp_editor settings array so it is added when tinymce is initialized. the The settings array is workinG. I can add or remove media buttons. However, I can't seem to get the right code inserted into the settings to get it to fire something when the active editor is changed.

Here is what I have.

```
$editorSettings = 
array ( 'media_buttons' => false,
        'resize' => false,
        'wp_autoresize_on' => true,
        'setup' => "function(ed) {
                      ed.onChange.add(function(ed, l) {
                        console.debug('Editor contents was modified. Contents: ' + l.content);
                      });
                    });" 
  );
```

Building editor with this code.

```
<?php wp_editor( stripslashes($j->journal_entry), 'journal-edit-'.$i , $editorSettings  ); ?>
```

Ideally I would just run the AJAX save code I have already written. However, the change event does not appear to be firing.

Is this the best way to do this or should I create something outside of wp_editor functions. I can find lots of code to manually start tinymce and modify it but not when trying to go through Wordpress.

I've thought about setting up hidden fields to compare but this seems like a bad way to go. There should be some build in functionality to utilize instead of creating it from scratch.

Thank you for your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like you do not want to do this through the settings array. Instead, add a filter to insert this code pre_init. The following code "clicks" a save button and prints to console on change event from tinymce in wordpress.

The setup js string needs to be minified or it will throw errors in console.

Add something like this to your functions.php file. NOTE: ' needed to be escaped in some of this code so it did not error out the functions file.

```
function mce_autosave_mod( $init ) {
    $init['setup'] = 'function(a){a.on("change",function(b){jQuery(this).parent().find(\'#btnEditCharJournal\').trigger("click"),console.log("the event object ",b),console.log("the editor object ",a),console.log("the content ",a.getContent())})}';     
    return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'mce_autosave_mod');
```

All kinds of other code could be thrown in here. It is a good idea to also add logic to limit this to the specific editor on your site. You don't want this running for all of the instances of the editor.

If you have any suggestions to clean this up or do it a better way please let me know. I am fairly new to filters and wp_editor/tinymce.